# occurrences of a string in another string using nested loops

Tags: java, loops

the exercise asking for using only **loops** not **construction functions or arrays** every help on all sites using arrays and construction functions.
I took a week to reach the code, and study alot of trials and looking for similar problem set but all help , not reach to last step
input:
string 1: ooo
string 2: Wooooooooow

output:
7 that not correct

output must be **(3)**
my code working in all strings input but incorrect at duplicated letters

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text1 = input.nextLine();
    String text2 = input.nextLine();
    int res = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<text2.length()-text1.length();i++)
    {
       if (text1.charAt(0) == text2.charAt(i))
       {
          boolean found = true;
          for (int j=0;j<text1.length() && found;j++)
              if (text1.charAt(j) != text2.charAt(i+j))
                  found = false;
          if (found)
              res++;
       }
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. With the following changes, your code will work as expected:

1. Increment `i` by `text1.length() - 1` each time `text1` is found and `j == text1.length()`. After you increment `i` by `text1.length() - 1`, the [loop's increment part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) will increment `i` by `1` which will result into `i` being incremented by `text1.length()`.
2. Modify the condition from `i < text2.length() - text1.length()` to `i < text2.length()`.
3. Modify the condition from `j<text1.length() && found` to `j < text1.length() && found && i + j < text2.length()`.

You can also make your program more efficient by breaking the inner loop as soon as the condition, `text1.charAt(j) != text2.charAt(i + j)` becomes `true`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the substring: ");
        String text1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the string to search into: ");
        String text2 = input.nextLine();
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < text2.length(); i++) {
            if (text1.charAt(0) == text2.charAt(i)) {
                boolean found = true;
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < text1.length() && found && i + j < text2.length(); j++) {
                    if (text1.charAt(j) != text2.charAt(i + j)) {
                        found = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (j == text1.length() && found) {
                    res++;
                    i += text1.length() - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the substring: ooo
Enter the string to search into: Wooooooooow
3
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help but when I check for input: string 1: the                                   
string2: the studentsth aretworkingthehardinthefacultyofthe -                                         output: 3 incorrect output it must be 4.

Comment: I trying to be continue this course, and I took off continue the course to understand this problem set

Comment: could you help all visitors like me before to this solution, with exact alogrithms to reach the idea.

Comment: @MohamedElkady - That's a good idea. I will do it sometime today.

Comment: when I check again string1:the - string2:the students are working hard in the faculty of Engineering because they love it - the output is an error please check again @Arvind Kumar Avinash - for this reason I asking for alogrithems- the try(ooo / Wooooooooow) and (the / the studentsth aretworkingthehardinthefacultyofthe)

Comment: you are  ...(what I can say) Thanks , but this problem I think in all sites not completed until know, I going to stop studing this course to study this solution

Comment: @MohamedElkady - I have put a flow diagram to make it easier for you and future visitors to understand the program. I won't be available for a couple of hours. Feel free to drop a note in case of any issue/doubt and I will look into that once I'm back.

Answer (score 1):

When found, you need to skip the found text.

Since loop does `i++`, that means:

```java
if (found) {
    res++;
    i += text1.length() - 1;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Also, the code will not find the substring if it is at the end of the string, because the outer loop ends early, so change `<` to `<=`:

```java
for (int i = 0; i <= text2.length() - text1.length(); i++) {
```

Comment: It will fail for the input, string 1: `the` and string2: `the studentsth aretworkingthehardinthefacultyofthe`.

Comment: @Andreas could you make your solution and flowchart  to study and make tests to figure the mistakes. thanks

Comment: @MohamedElkady Huh? You asked for help figuring out what was wrong with your code, and this answer covers that *in full*. StackOverflow is not a teaching site, so I'm not sure what else you're asking about. If you want a flow chart, draw one.

Comment: @Andreas this program become a learning path for me or any one, and if there is alot discussion the more information and tech we learn.  thanks